# How to change the color of custom svg icon in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to change the color of a custom svg icon on clicking a button

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-icon src="../../assets/img/icon-qr.svg"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>Qr Scan</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: `<ion-icon class="something".....` then in css `.something { fill: red }`

Comment: Just add a `css class` on click event in which `color:something;` is defined!

Comment: @ChrisW. Already tried { fill: red } but it is not working. The custom svg icon color is not changing in ionic 4. The same icon is worked fine in ionic 3. Is the above implementation is correct in ionic 4?

Answer (score 23):

I was unable to override an svg stroke or fill if it was specified in the svg.

**Example: bad svg**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="16" viewBox="0 0 20 16">
  <g fill="#88AACC" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#555555" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2">
     ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

Removing `fill="#88AACC"` & `stroke="#555555"` from within the SVG itself then allowed it to be controlled from CSS as you'd expect.

```
.some-class {
  fill: red;
  stroke: blue;
}
```

Comment: most helpful hint to check the colors within the svg. helped me a lot

Comment: This is a valid solution with Ionic 6!

Comment: @Ashley Medway You can also change the fill into fill="currentColor" to make it follow the color too

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the entire style attribute inside the path of your custom icon,
Ionic adds its default style instead.

```
<path
 style="APPLIED STYLE"
 d="DRAWN PATH"
/>
```

After removing the style attribute, the custom icon can be used like e.g. ionicons.

```
<IonIcon icon={CUSTOM_ICON} color="primary" />
```

Ionic sets the fill property of the svg when the color attribute is used. Stroke color e.g. if used for outline icons is not set.

Answer (score 1):

its working fine see below

**page.html**

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-icon src="/assets/images/box.svg" color="primary" style="fill: brown;"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>Qr Scan</ion-label>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-icon src="/assets/images/boxing.svg" style="fill: brown;"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Qr Scan</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it not working !!

Answer (score 1):

for me only i had to remove fill property `fill="#000000"` from the svg file

```
``<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

`xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"`
`viewBox="0 0 60 60" style="enable-background:new 0 0 496 496;"`
`xml:space="preserve">`
`<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`

`<path ...... fill="#000000" />`

`<path ...... fill="#000000" />`

`<path ...... fill="#000000" />`

and  then on my Ion-icon  i did like so

```
<ion-icon style="fill: white;" ></ion-icon>
```

that solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the **style** and the **fill** of your custom svg path.
Example:

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Change it to this :

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d=""/>
</svg>
```