# Can't change the stroke color of Ionicon 5 outline set

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, ionicons

I am trying to color the outline version of Ionicons 5, but there are inline styles for stroke and fill. I tried targeting the icon using a class and setting both fill and stroke color, as well and using just the color property. The fills color using the CSS color property, but it has no affect on the stroke. If I set the stroke color and inspect, it is overridden by the inline stroke property value.

Is there a way to override this style? Can I reach in and grab the child path or stroke using CSS so that I can override the SVG stroke color that is default to Ionicons?

HTML

`<ion-icon class="ico-top" name="pizza-outline"></ion-icon>`

CSS

```
ion-icon {
color: $current-color;
stroke: $current-color;
fill: $current-color;
}
```

The `color` and `fill` properties work on parts of the icons, but won't override the inline stroke value. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem. Remove your current `<script>` and replace it with those ones :

```
[ionicons] Deprecated script, please remove: <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
To improve performance it is recommended to set the differential scripts in the head as follows:
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
```

Comment: The documentation needs to be updated. This was the fix for me too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom imported Ionic 5 icons you can remove the stroke="#XXXXXX" attribute from the .svg file itself.

After that the css attribute `stroke` will work fine on the `ion-icon` selector.

See also this answer here: [How to change the color of custom svg icon in ionic 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489636/how-to-change-the-color-of-custom-svg-icon-in-ionic-4)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this changing the svg code: `stroke="currentColor"`. This will make the stroke adopt the color you defined in `ion-icon`'s style `color`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the css variable `--ionicon-stroke-width`

```
ion-icon {
  --ionicon-stroke-width: 16px;
}
```

From the [Ionicons usage page](https://ionic.io/ionicons/usage)